# Strings not being stored using SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save two Strings in SharedPreferences. When i first run the app they display as supposed to. When i close the app and re open the app the Strings are no longer set to what they were before the closing of the app and the default String value is used. Why is this? Below are my methods for saving and retrieving the two Strings.

Here are the two Strings

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

    playerName1 = intent.getStringExtra("PLAYER_ONE");
    playerName2 = intent.getStringExtra("PLAYER_TWO");
```

Here is the method to store the Strings

```
private void savePlayerNames()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("playerNames", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("playerOne", playerName1);
    editor.putString("playerTwo", playerName2);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Here is where they are retrieved

```
private void displayPlayerNames(int current)
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("playerNames", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String playerOne = sharedPreferences.getString("playerOne","Player 1");
    String playerTwo = sharedPreferences.getString("playerTwo","Player 2");

    if(playerchoice[current].getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        if (savedTracker % 2 == 0)
        {
            playerchoice[current].setText(x);
            playerNameDisplay.setText(playerTwo + "'s Go!");
            savedTracker++;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps the extras do not contain what you think they do. Perhaps you are not calling `savePlayerNames()`. Step through your code in the debugger to find out, or add enough logging statements to be able to determine what is going on in Logcat. BTW, it is a good idea to define values like `"playerNames"` and `"playerOne"` -- values that you use in a few places and must stay the same -- as constants, rather than repeating the strings.

Comment: The extras defo contain what is expcted as the Strings display properly when the app is first run, it is only when the app is closed and opened again they are switched to the defaults.

Comment: I would suggest you to look into file explorer for the device in Android Studio. So file explorer -> your application -> shared_prefs and then you should see your XML. Open it and see if it contains the values you've submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
editor.commit();
```

with

```
editor.apply();
```

`commit()` writes its preferences out to persistent storage `synchronously`, which may failed because of various reasons.
`apply(`) writes its changes to the inmemory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an `asynchronous` commit to disk.

apply() is completely safe. You can use it without worry as you will get updated value of preferences.

Comment: That did it, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following class. This will help you get rid of all the confusing code

```
public class PlayersData {

private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private static final String PLAYERS_DATA = "PLAYERS_DATA";
private static final String PLAYERS = "PLAYERS";

public PlayersData(Context context) {
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PLAYERS_DATA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
}

public void savePlayers(Players players) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(players);
    editor.putString(PLAYERS, json);
    editor.commit();
}

public Players getPlayers() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString(PLAYERS, null);
    return gson.fromJson(json, Players.class);
}

public class Players{

    private String one;
    private String two;

    public Players() {

    }

    public Players(String one, String two) {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }

    public String getOne() {
        return one;
    }

    public void setOne(String one) {
        this.one = one;
    }

    public String getTwo() {
        return two;
    }

    public void setTwo(String two) {
        this.two = two;
    }
}

}
```

To get/save data simple initialize class and do operations:

```
PlayersData playersData = new PlayersData(this); //this is the context
```

One thing I forgot to mention is that I have used gson lib so add this line to your app level Gradle file and build your Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```